# tinyMCE duplicates previous block element when pressing return (visual editor)

Tags: tinymce, visual-editor, post-editor

Going crazy with this. Can't figure out if this is normal behavior.

I have added a filter to rewrite image inserts to use `<figure>` and `<figcaption>`. Works well.

However, when I insert an image in the Visual view and press return, I want it to start a new paragraph.

Instead it creates another `<figure>` element and puts my next line of text in that.

Example of the code produced if switch to Text view:

```
<figure class="alignnone">

<a href="path/to/image.jpg"><img class="alignnone size- wp-image-209" src="path/to/image.jpg" width="199" height="43" /></a>

<figcaption>Image Caption</figcaption>

</figure>

<figure class="alignnone"`>This should be a new paragraph but is inside a figure tag.</figure>
```

Is there any way I can stop tinyMCE from replicating the previous block element? I know if you set some text as, say, an `<h2>` and press return the next line defaults back to `<p>`. That's the behavior I want.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently having the same problem. Here's my work-around.

```
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'workaround' );
public function workaround( $in ) {
    $in['force_br_newlines'] = true;
    $in['force_p_newlines'] = false;
    $in['forced_root_block'] = '';
    return $in;
}
```

tiny_mce_before_init gives you access to the TinyMCE settings that WordPress' editor uses. See also: [TinyMCEConfiguration](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration)

The downside to this is instead of "return" resulting in a **p** it instead gives you a **br**. I've tried reversing the **force_br_newlines** and **force_p_newlines** but it results in the original problem. Hope this is of some help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but not in Wordpress. Anyway, I force the 'p' block to take the content between 'p' tags. And because of that, when I hit the return button and save the content into DB the TinyMce duplicates the 'p' tags. Moreover, it duplicates the tags all the times I save it again. My solution is into the init:

```
force_br_newlines: true,
force_p_newlines: false,
forced_root_block: 'p',
invalid_elements: 'p',
```

The most important is the invalid_elements. Here you have to list the 'p' tag. After this setting my code does not duplicate the 'p' tag anymore. Hope your's will do the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `keep_styles` option to `false` on init.

This option will keep the editor's current text style when a user presses enter/return.

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  keep_styles: false
});
```

Taken from the [docs](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#keep_styles)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nother version of the solution. I have to write a new one, because the previous one is OK, but it not works with every other settings.
This solution stops duplicating `p` tags after new lines and headings, but puts one simple `br` tag between the paragraphs.

```
forced_root_block: 'p',
force_p_newlines: false,
force_br_newlines: false,
extended_valid_elements: '-p',
```

I use the extended_valid_elements because I do not want to redefine the default setting, just one value of the valid_elements. The meaning of -p and the other settings are [here](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#valid_elements).

**Note** that with this setting, you will see bigger space between the text elements in the editor visually.